# How to define the peak of a curve in geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm doing a node network using instances along a path. Although the instances are behaving correctly from the endpoints onward; it's until they approach the focus and towards the peak they're not aligning with the path. Also I want to delete the highest point on the instance without affecting the rest of them. Is there a method of defining the top curve and editing it? Here are some screenshots of the problem:

[image]

*Instances along the curve are not fully aligned.*

[image]

*Instances node setup.*

[image]

*Quadratic bezier setup. The instances will be realized along the network.*

Comment: pls provide blend file so we don't have to rebuild everything on our own. This will attract more people who want to answer (like me). Thanks. if you don't want, i am pretty sure this can be solved with the attribute statistic node and the delete geometry node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of unclear to me from your question what you want to rotate and how, so I can only make guesses.

However, when instantiating along a curve, you can omit the center point by simply dividing the number of points and comparing it to the current index.

You then use the selection obtained in this way directly in the instantiation:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I should've made my question more specific. This was my primary problem. The rest was secondary.